# How to kmeans to clustor datetime by period weakly, montly and yearly

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have a list of bills with id, merchant name and paid date, I want to cluster this data based on the period this bills are paid, meaning the outcome result of the clustering should group the bills paid weakly together, and the bills paid monthly together and so on

Comment: Why do you need to use k-means for that? You could simply divide the time interval into weeks and treat that as your groups.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius How is that is going to help when I want to group the data to group of periods  weekly, monthly and yearly